# Position of the two divs

Tags: html, css

I've got two div elements in my webpage and I've included the CSS for the two elements.

```
#item-browsing {
    width: 65%;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 915px;
}

#bill-information {
    width: 315px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 3px -3px 11px -7px;
}
```

When I re-size the browser for various resolutions the item-browsing element goes down. I've attached a screen shot of what I mean above.

[image: Browser Screen Shot]

How Can I fix this issue using CSS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give parent element of these two elements `position: relative` and change the following css related to `#item-browsing`.

```
#item-browsing {
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 315px; /* or left */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 915px;
}
```

BTW, there are many posts based on this issue on SO.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wFApP/1/)

Comment: This made the exact output I wanted! thank you. :) Sorry to bother you guys but I din't know exactly what to search on. I searched on making the bill-information div stick to the other but did not find any results.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a wrapper around those two divs. like so:

```
#wrapper{
width: [your width];
clear: both;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

#item-browsing {
    width: 65%;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 915px;
}

#bill-information {
    width: 315px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 3px -3px 11px -7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper and set it's `min-width` with sum of width of both containing divs:

```
#wrapper {
    min-width: 1230px;
}
```

[**Simplified demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wFApP/)

Answer (score -1):

If the browser width is less than 915 (min-width)+315(width)=1230px the second div has no space on the right side.